# How to show Initial content of Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to show content of `$('.modal').find('.modal-content').html($('.modal-content').eq(0).html());` on modal at initial stage always when click on `"#plan_templates"` button.

But I am getting content of `$('.modal').find('.modal-content').html($('.modal-content').eq(0).html());` on modal at first time when I click on `"#plan_templates"` button. I am getting content of `$('.modal').find('.modal-content').html($('.tab').eq(index).html());` on modal at second time.

Here's my code showing the bootstrap modal.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#plan_templates").click(function() {
        $('.modal').find('.modal-content').html($('.modal-content').eq(0).html());
        $(".modal").modal("show");

        $(".tplan").click(function() {
            var index = $(".tplan").index(this);
            $('.modal').find('.modal-content').html($('.tab').eq(index).html());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is your `.tplan` button exists? Is it inside `$('.modal-content').eq(0).html()` ?

Comment: How many `.model` and `.model-content` elements are there in your page? Why are you using `indexed` queryselector ?

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: You have a click function being bound inside another click function. That's not good practice as it creates new event handlers with every click. Please revise to show some HTML.